# How to test Azure Marketplace offer?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I created VM for publishing on Azure Marketplace. But I want to test it before I publish it for all. Besides, the publication takes several days.

How to test my offer before publishing on Azure Marketplace?

UPDATE:

I see next screen on Cloud Partner Portal:

[image]

Should I publish offer before I can test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to test exactly? you can test the [ui definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/test-createuidefinition) and template separately. you  will also have to undergo testing from MS before publication, [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/1-CONTRIBUTION-GUIDE/README.md#travis-ci) readme talks about it in some detail.

You would test template like you normally would.

Comment: I only started work with Azure Marketplace and created simple VM offer for test. I need create Managed Application with a lot of resources and servers. I want to test how it will work together before publication.

Comment: I want to deploy the offer to my account without publishing it on Marketplace. Is it possible?

Comment: just deploy a template like you normally would, or you can create a managed application using the same Ui definition to mimic marketplace workflow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/overview

Comment: I need ability to create new servers dynamically over API. Managed Apps provide this ability. But I need to test how it will work for final users.

Comment: It seems I do not understand something. I created App, but how I can test it? I must publish it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/publish-managed-app-definition-quickstart and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/deploy-service-catalog-quickstart

Comment: Could you please help me with next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329588/azure-marketplace-is-it-possible-to-use-images-in-managed-application-offer

Answer (score 1):

When you click the Publish button, your offer will be just validated and in preview mode for the subscriptions list you can specify in your offer. This validation takes 40 - 80 minutes. 
After that you can send your offer for manual validation by Microsoft engineers, it takes 3-5 days, and your application will be published on Azure Marketplace