# Can't deploy my Managed Application from Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I created Azure Managed Application.

I successful deployed it to my subscription over Service catalog managed application definitions like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631186/1035334).

Next I published it on Azure Marketplace. But when I try to deploy it from Marketplace, I see message "Your deployment is underway" infinitely. No errors, but the app does not deploy.

[image]

UPDATE:

Deployment failed after 2 hours with next error message: "The resource provision operation did not complete within the allowed timeout period".

[image]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To investigate this issue, you can open the created managed resource group and research the   "Deployment" tab

Comment: Thank you. I found next error in Related events:
PrincipalNotFound: Principal *** does not exist in the directory ***. I specified my tenant id and my app id in settings of SKU.
Can you suggest something about this error?

Comment: What was the resource which threw the exception?

Comment: Did you try to specify service principal id? You can find it using Azure PowerShell: Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString <Your registered application name>. As I know, you should take objectId from an output of this command. More docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: Yes, I used my app ID. Problem solved after I changed Principal to group ID. But now I have next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329588/azure-marketplace-is-it-possible-to-use-images-in-managed-application-offer

Can you halp?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to open a support request with the Azure Marketplace on this one...  we'll need details that are not public.